# How to perform normal and regex search on huge text lines using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

I have huge log data content to be shown on the browser for which it's rendered with each line in a `pre` tag like the following for it to look clean.

```
<div id="log_block">
    <pre class="logs" id="line_1">00:00:00.001 INFO Current Directory C:/DATA</pre>
    <pre class="logs" id="line_2">00:00:00.001 INFO No image info file found</pre>
    <pre class="logs" id="line_3">00:00:00.001 INFO Command line: ls -l</pre>
    .
    .
    <pre class="logs" id="line_10000">00:20:10.001 INFO Command line</pre>
</div>
```

The application has a search box where users can make normal search for a phrase or regex search.

When any user searches for a text, I have used find function of the browser to show the searched word, wherein I'm hiding all the lines that do not contain that word.

```
function find_searched_word() {
    val = $('#search_bar').val();
    $('#log_block pre:not(:contains("' + val + '"))').hide();
}
```

For regex search, I'm looping through each line of pre to check if it matches and store in variable and then renders it.

```
html_content = '';
$("#log_block pre").each(function(i){
   if(this.html().match(regex))
      html_content = html_content + this;
});
```

For loglines up to 20,000+ lines the process is fast but when log lines cross 100,000+ lines then search becomes very slow and sometimes page stucks.

What is the best alternative to performing a phrase and regex search for 100,000+ text lines rendered on the browser?

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood. I'm quite sure a lot of people won't understand what `crosses a lakh` means.

Comment: Well, you have 100k HTML tags to search over a DOM, what did you expect?

You should NOT print all those amounts of logs and then try to search over it 

So my advice is if this comes from a database, then do the search there and allow ONLY at least 3 digits or 4 or 5... so you don't search "a" for example as you might have A LOT of possible results...

This is a common behavior, and you can't do too much about this. On the other hand, you could try to use a variable instead of printing the results, print the minimum and search over that variable, I think it's faster than trying on DOM